# How to start GWT in web mode?

Tags: java, gwt, eclipse-plugin, mode

I'm using the Eclipse GWT plugin to start my GWT application. It's always starting in "development mode". How can I start it in web mode? (I guess that one doesn't need the Firefox Plugin?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Compile it and run

If you link http://.....?gwt... it will run in hosted mode

If you delete all after '?' it will run in web mode

Answer (score 0):

compile and has a tomcat refer  gwt war directory.

start tomcat. you can get normal url.